# Não aparece nome das coluna no jTable

Tags: java, mysql

Criei um JScrollPane e nele um jTable, isso tudo dentro de um JInternalFrame, mas quando executo meu Jframe e abro esse JInternalFrame, ele só mostra os dados em linhas que estão no meu banco de dados, mas não mostra lá em cima os nomes das colunas.
Código do JInternalFrame

```
public class Listar extends javax.swing.JDialog {

private AnnotationResolver resolver;
private ObjectTableModel otm;
private UsuarioDao dao;
/**
 * Creates new form Listar
 * @param parent
 * @param modal
 */
public Listar(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    resolver = new AnnotationResolver(modelo.Usuario.class);
    otm = new ObjectTableModel(resolver, "nome,sobrenome,email,departamento");
    try {
        dao = new UsuarioDao();
        otm.setData(dao.listarTodasAsPessoaList());
        jTable1.setModel(otm);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Listar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}


private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 385, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(75, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 283, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
} private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;}
```

Comment: Adicione na pegunta um código que seja um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testa-lo, e o seu `ObjectTableModel`